# VBA Vlookup within loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, vlookup

The user enters usernames in inputboxes ("Enter username"), which appear in the first column from row 4 onwards (specified as cells (4+k-1,1) in the code). The number of usernames he enters corresponds to the number of users he indicates were active on a certain date, specified in the first inputbox ("How many users active on this date?").

Now, I want the next column (cells(4+k-1,2)) to execute a vlookup or similar function that takes the username in the first column (same row) and finds a corresponding value in a table in a different worksheet (same workbook!). The problem is that no matter what I try, I can't find a code that makes this work. My most simple attempt is presented in the code as follows, and returns a message "run time error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error".

```
Sub Makro4()
    Dim dates As Date
    dates = InputBox("Enter the date of activity in the format dd/mm/yyyy:.")  ' User chooses date

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    n = InputBox("Number of users active on this date:.")

    For k = 1 To n + 1                                       'Inserts rows accoring to number of users active on specified date
        Rows(4).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
              CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next

    For k = 1 To n
        Cells(4 + k - 1, 1) = InputBox("Enter username")
        Cells(4 + k - 1, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Users by date").Range(4 + k - 1, 1), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Userlist").Range("B:j"), 9, False)
    Next

    Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(4 + n - 1, 3)) = dates ' blank row between each date

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I've attempted to do this a hundred different ways but if I run the code that i pasted here then at the "Cells (4+k-1,2) =. ...." part I get the error message "Run time error 1004: application defined or object defined error".
I pasted this particular code because it's easy to follow and you can see where my problems occur, unlike some of my other failed attempts (this is the first macro I've ever written...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested, but compiles)

Notes:

1) Always try to qualify every use of `Range()` or `Cells()` with a worksheet object

2) If you drop the `WorkSheetFunction` then you can test the return value to see if it is an error, instead of having vlookup trigger a run-time error if there's no match

```
Sub Makro4()
    Dim dates As Date
    dates = InputBox("Enter the date of activity in the format dd/mm/yyyy:.")  ' User chooses date

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim usr, v
    Dim shtUBD As Worksheet, shtUsers As Worksheet

    Set shtUBD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Users by date")
    Set shtUsers = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Userlist")

    n = InputBox("Number of users active on this date:.")

    For k = 1 To n + 1 'Inserts rows accoring to number of users active on specified date
        shtUBD.Rows(4).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
              CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next

    For k = 1 To n
        usr = InputBox("Enter username")
        'If you drop the "WorkSheetFunction" then you can test the
        '  return value using IsError(), else it will raise an
        '  error if there's no match found for the username...
        v = Application.VLookup(usr, shtUsers.Range("B:J"), 9, False)

        With shtUBD.Rows(4 + k - 1)
            .Cells(1).Value = usr
            .Cells(2).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "?User?", v)
        End With
    Next
    ' blank row between each date
    shtUBD.Range(shtUBD.Cells(4, 3), shtUBD.Cells(4 + n - 1, 3)) = dates

End Sub
```

Comment: fantastic thank you tim! works a charm. some great tips &  code in there too. much appreciated!

Comment: Can I just ask, when you say "Dim usr, v", does this indicate to VBA that v is in the column to the right of usr? EDIT: actually I think you specifiy this in the "With" function thing (Cells(1) & Cells(2)) right? EDIT 2: I'm such a noob

Comment: No - all it says is "create two variables of unspecified type named `usr` and `v`"  Both default to type `Variant`, and the order is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the first `Range` description in the `VLOOKUP` function.  If you want to use row/col numbers then use `Cells` to describe the range.

To avoid yourself a lot of typing experiment with this, which should fix your immediate issue:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Users by date")
    For k = 1 To n
        Cells(4 + k - 1, 1) = InputBox("Enter username")
        Cells(4 + k - 1, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(4 + k - 1, 1), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B:j"), 9, False)
    Next
End With
```

Comment: cheers barry this worked too! i must have tried a million things like this without getting there! i have a feeling that i was hitting my keyboard instead of typing out some real usernames a lot of the time, and that would be the error - which,as tim mentioned i could have avoided. thanks so much for this, my first macro is looking great